# Your JET project does not have oraclejet-tooling installed

Tags: visual-studio, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I recently installed Oracle jet and I haven't made any changes to it. I created my first project today and it's showing error when I try to build it or serve it. I am trying to run it on Visual Studio (I don't this matters tho)

This is the error I am getting

```
PM> ojet serve ojet : [31mError: Your JET project does not have oraclejet-tooling installed.[0m  
At line:1 char:
+ ojet serve
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ([31mError: You... installed.[0m:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

**UPDATE**: Apparently when I create a new template it is creating an error from there itself the app structure is generated but during invoking mom install it is unable to parse through some certain JSON

Following is the Error:

```
ojet create ojetnavbar --template=navbar
Processing template: navbar
Your app structure is generated. Continuing with library install.
Performing npm install may take a bit.
Invoking npm install.
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...oIzTWjIvO8rspcLCK+1pI'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     *location of log*
Error: (during Invoking npm install.) 1
```

Comment: Are you behind a firewall by any chance? The npm command is failing while trying to install dependencies.  Usually this is related to a network issue of some kind. You can just run the command again and it may work fine.  I've seen npm hang up from time to time.

Comment: The only times I've faced any errors with OJET installations were when there were network problems, like being connected to a VPN without knowing, or sitting behind a proxy server but that proxy wasn't configured for npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted out on the issue it was because the JSON npm was trying to parse were mostly cached and due to that a parsing error was occurring

I used `npm-cache clean` on my PC and all of it ran after that perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

`$ npm install -g @oracle/ojet-cli
   $ npm install -g @oracle/oraclejet-tooling 
   $ ojet restore`

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add oraclejet tooling to your project. Try this:

```
cd appDir
npm install @oracle/oraclejet-tooling --save
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it gives 404 error, updated the problem a bit maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

oraclejet-tooling package has been deprecated, you have to use module contains a command-line interface for Oracle JET web and hybrid mobile application development.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@oracle/ojet-cli

```
cd oracle-jet-simple-web
npm install @oracle/ojet-cli --save
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this helped

```
npm i @oracle/oraclejet-tooling
```

Here is the link: [npmjs.com/package/@oracle/oraclejet-tooling](https://npmjs.com/package/@oracle/oraclejet-tooling)

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to get started.